# Excel - keep sum value when deleting value from cell

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have very basic knowledge with ms excel, I don't really need it. But at the moment I could really use it. My problem is with summing. I have 13 cell which are summed. 
Now every time I delete the value or change it keeps recalculating my sum cell. I would like that it keeps adding i.e. I have cells from D1 to D13 and I sum it with `SUM(D1:D13)` now if I put in D2->3 and in D5->2 the sum is 5 if I change D5 to 3 the sum will be 6 but I would like it to be 8. So it keeps adding the values if cells.

I really appreciate any help

Comment: Do you mind to post a screenshot of what you have so far?

Comment: you would need vba to do this

Comment: yeah, I thought so Shiva. I put it as a tag but someone want it to remove it. Do you have any idea how Shiva?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using vba:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(Byval Target as Range)
if not intersect(Range("D13,D20"),target) is nothing then
    Range("D37") = Range("D37") + target.value
end if
end sub
```